# jQuery multi click event check

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-click-event

You can access full code with github pages link below. [Link](https://sangumee.github.io/Udacity-Memory-Game/)

In HTML Code looks like this.

```
<ul class="deck">
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-diamond"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-anchor"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-bolt"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-cube"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-anchor"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-leaf"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-bicycle"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-diamond"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-bomb"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-leaf"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-bomb"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-bolt"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-bicycle"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-cube"></i>
            </li>
```

and the JavaScript Code is like this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.card').click(function () {
        // Card Open
        $(this).addClass("open show");

        // Save First Click i element className
        let firstclick = ($(this).children('.fa'));
        console.log(firstclick);
        // Save Second Click i element className
        let secondclick = ($(this).children('.fa'));
        console.log(secondclick);

        // compare first click element and second element to match card
        if (firstclick === secondclick) {
            // if match each other change card class to "card match"
            $(this).removeClass("open show");
            $(this).addClass("match")
        } else {
            // if not match each other close card after 2 seconds.
            let ele = $(this);
            setTimeout(function () {
                ele.removeClass("open show");
            }, 2000);
        }
    })
});
```

As you can see my comment. When I click the li element, check i tag which is inside the li element and save it into firstclick variable. and secondclick also the same. And compare each other and if it is match change class to "card match" but if not, after 2 seconds it should change "card" class to close the card.

but I have some question how can I save the firstclick and secondclick
In my console.log when I click the li element it just save same variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it because everytime you click $(this) will select your clicked
>   element so it does firstclick, secondclick get same value order to avoid this i am using seq controller for logic as you can **see below**

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
  var sequenceController = 1,
    firstclick, secondclick;
  $('.card').click(function() {
    // Card Open
    $(this).addClass("open show");

    switch (sequenceController) {
      case 1:
        firstclick = ($(this).children('.fa').attr('class'));
        sequenceController++;
        break;
      case 2:
        secondclick = ($(this).children('.fa').attr('class'));
        sequenceController--;
        if (firstclick == secondclick) {
          $('.open.show').removeClass("open show").addClass("match");
          alert('matched')
        } else {
          $('.open.show').removeClass("open show")
          firstclick = '1';
          secondclick = '2';
          alert('not matched')
        }
        break;
    }




  })

});
```

Comment: oh i just tested in jsfiddle let me fix that

Comment: Thanks for the reply!. I will wait Thanks!!. I just test your code but I'm wondering why It's not wokring.

Comment: I edited with this code. but still not working. Even if matched, but still cards are closing after 2 seconds.

Comment: @sangumee works fine in fiddle if you want fiddle you can have it let me know oke

Comment: If Fiddle is available, I would appreciate it if you could.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily fix that by adding some booleans to your jQuery.

```
var isFirstClick = true;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.card').click(function () {
        $(this).addClass("open show");

        var firstclick, secondclick;

        if ( isFirstClick ) {
            firstclick = ($(this).children('.fa'));
            console.log(firstclick);
            isFirstClick = false;
        }
        else {
            secondclick = ($(this).children('.fa'));
            console.log(secondclick);
            isFirstClick = true;
        }

        if (firstclick === secondclick) {
            $(this).removeClass("open show");
            $(this).addClass("match")
        } else {
            let ele = $(this);
            setTimeout(function () {
                ele.removeClass("open show");
            }, 2000);
       }
    })
});
```

Comment: when I use this method there are some errors.  `Uncaught ReferenceError: firstclick is not defined
    at HTMLLIElement.<anonymous> (app.js:104)
    at HTMLLIElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLLIElement.y.handle (jquery.min.js:2)`
I think there is firstclick variable but why cannot defined,

Comment: Yes, sorry, when I put the if around it it messed up the scopes, so I think if you put, the `var firstclick; var secondclick;` before the `if ( isFirstClick)` and in the if you just write `firstclick=($(this).children('.fa'))` and the same with secondclick it might solve this error.